# What does @# mean in the C preprocessor?

Tags: c-preprocessor

What does `@#expression1, expression2, @#expression2` mean in the context below?

The code is Objective-C, but Objective-C still uses the C preprocessor.

```c
#define XCTAssertEqualObjects(expression1, expression2, ...) \
    _XCTPrimitiveAssertEqualObjects(self, expression1, @#expression1, expression2, @#expression2, __VA_ARGS__)

#define _XCTPrimitiveAssertEqualObjects(test, expression1, expressionStr1, expression2, expressionStr2, ...) \
({ \
    @try { \
        id expressionValue1 = (expression1); \
        id expressionValue2 = (expression2); \
        if ((expressionValue1 != expressionValue2) && ![expressionValue1 isEqual:expressionValue2]) { \
            _XCTRegisterFailure(test, _XCTFailureDescription(_XCTAssertion_EqualObjects, 0, expressionStr1, expressionStr2, expressionValue1, expressionValue2), __VA_ARGS__); \
        } \
    } \
    @catch (_XCTestCaseInterruptionException *interruption) { [interruption raise]; } \
    @catch (NSException *exception) { \
        _XCTRegisterFailure(test, _XCTFailureDescription(_XCTAssertion_EqualObjects, 1, expressionStr1, expressionStr2, [exception reason]), __VA_ARGS__); \
    } \
    @catch (...) { \
        _XCTRegisterFailure(test, _XCTFailureDescription(_XCTAssertion_EqualObjects, 2, expressionStr1, expressionStr2), __VA_ARGS__); \
    } \
})
```

Comment: Are you sure that's C?

Comment: This looks like Objective-C.

Comment: Yes, this isn't C. It's Objective-C, but Objective-C still has the same preprocessor as C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XCTAssertEqualObjects` is turning the expression you're verifying into a string, so in the event of a failure, it can print the expression that failed (through `_XCTPrimitiveAssertEqualObjects` and `_XCTRegisterFailure`).

In the C preprocessor, using a `#` will [stringify](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html) whatever's passed in, so you can use it as a constant. By prefixing `@` to the string, it becomes an Objective-C string constant.